# how to alter values in a field of a json array with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I would like to assign different values to a same field in a json array using jq command line utility,

for example let's take this:

```
myjson='[{"a":1,"b":"john"}, {"a":2, "b":"mark"}]'
```

with the following I can assign all fields a same value

```
echo $myjson | jq '[.[] | .a=5 ]'
```

I can also increment it:

```
echo $myjson | jq '[.[] | .a+=2]'
```

but how can I assign two new different values like 7  and 3  to the two a fields in the objects in the array?

using the following, or similar assigns a whole array to each variable

```
echo $myjson | jq '[.[] | .a=[7,3]]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your scheme, there is no such solution because all of your filters address all items "at once", meaning independently from their position in the array. That's why you can only set them to the same value or otherwise treat them in the same way, without using their index, which would be needed to address the specific new value to be used.

To achieve your goal, you will have to iterate over either array indices or the aligned elements.

The former could be implemented by using `reduce` to iterate over the new values in combination with `to_entries` to access their position (key), and successively update the input array's items using key and value.

```
reduce ([3,7] | to_entries[]) as $i (.; .[$i.key].a = $i.value)
```

```json
[
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": "john"
  },
  {
    "a": 7,
    "b": "mark"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eJhHDXzjszC)

The latter could be implemented using the `transpose` builtin, which aligns elements of two (or any number of) arrays by matching their indices, and outputs them as a combined array.

```json
[., [3,7]] | [transpose[] | first + {a:last}]
```

```json
[
  {
    "a": 3,
    "b": "john"
  },
  {
    "a": 7,
    "b": "mark"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TcFt2tc985-)

---

Note: Your sample filters could be condensed to `.[].a = 5` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zxkmTDHZm6N)) and `.[].a += 2` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SF1ED9fWhkY)), respectively.